# Proving the context of the formula $\frac{k!}{k_1!\cdot k_2!...k_n!}$ - Need help to understand the context

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

> On $n$ cells $k$ distinguishable particles shall be distributed in
>   such a way that in the cell $i$ exactly $k_i$ particles lie,
>   $k_1+k_2+...+k_n=k$. An arrangement within each cell is not considered.
>   Show that the upper formula specifies the number of different
>   distributions.

So I have fixed $n$ cells what do I know about my $k$ objects do I have more than $n$ or less than $n$? All I can deduced from above Information is that I have to distribute every particle.

Also what does it mean that in the cell $i\,k_i$ particles lie what is $k_i$?

Comment: It means exactly what it says...the are $k_i$ particles in cell $i$.

Comment: can $k_i$ be Zero?

Comment: Sure.  all we know is that $k_i≥0 $ and $\sum k_i=k$

Comment: This is called the [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_to_multinomials).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sketch:

We know there are $k_1$ particles in the first cell, we need to select which $k_1$.  There are $\binom k{k_1}$ ways to do that.

Having done that we have to choose $k_2$ particles for the second cell.  There are $\binom {k-k_1}{k_2}$ ways to do that.

And so on.

The total count is then $$\binom k{k_1}\times \binom {k-k_1}{k_2}\times \cdots \times \binom {k-k_1-\cdots -k_{n-1}}{k_n}$$

Writing out the binomial coefficients we get $$\frac {k!}{k_1!\times (k-k_1)!}\times \frac {(k-k_1)!}{k_2!\times (k-k_1-k_2)!}\times \cdots$$

And cancellation of common terms does the rest.

Comment: what is missing to call it a proof?

Comment: @New2Math  Well, it's a bit hand-wavy at the end, I felt.

Comment: I want to understand why this Formula and this context is also the Formula for permutations with repeated Elements. In this context if I have a word with 5 letters where 2 are indistinguishable and I want to find out all Arrangements why does it have to be $\binom{5}{2}\cdot\binom{3}{1}\cdot\binom{2}{1}\cdot\binom{1}{1}$?

Comment: To establish the bijection, let the first cell correspond to the first letter, and let $k_1$ be the locations of the occurrences of that letter, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Some HINTS:

That formula is usually used for "permutations with repeated elements", that is for example:

How many different words can you make with the letters in MATHEMATICS?

The different permutations of these letters are $11!$ but there are some repeated letters so if I index the two "A"s for example then

$$
MA_1THEMA_2TICS
$$

and

$$
MA_2THEMA_1TICS
$$

are distinguishable but without the indices they are the same so we have to "remove" these cases by dividing by the number of ways we can arrange the "A"s in between themselves, that is $2!$.

So the total number of ways to arrange the letters will be

$$
\frac{11!}{2!\cdot2!}
$$

since we have $2$ "M"s as well. These are just some thoughts about the formula.

Now to answer your questions:

I wouldn´t say that $k$ is less than $n$ but nothing in the wording of the question would immediately say the opposite.

$k_i$ would be the number of particles ending up in cell number $i$.

Comment: If I have $12$ Sweaters and I want to pick $5$ out of them where 2 are indistinguishable how many choices do I have?